# printf(" LIST.H ") where LIST.H is a macro

Tags: c, macros, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define LIST.H onus;

int main ()
{
         char *p,*s;
         printf(" LIST.H ");
}
```

I expect LIST.H to print `onus` as out put.
But this does not happen.
upon compiling I get a warning

```
temp.c:3:13: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
```

and the output is LIST.H not onus.
How can I get desired thing printed by the above macro?

**UPDATE**
I want to have the output 
as `onus` with one space before and after the string.

Comment: I wonder if "onus" is a euphemism :)

Comment: It depends on your "desired thing". The code, as it is now, make very little sense, so there's no way to figure out what exactly that "desired thing" is. Basically, you can forget about macros entirely and do `printf("onus")`. That will print what you want. If that doesn't work for you, you have to explain in more detail what is it you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros names cannot have `.` inside them. That's why you get the warning:
`warning: missing whitespace after the macro name`, after `LIST` it expects a space, but it gets a `.` instead.

Also, when a macro name is inside a string(between `"string"`) it is not replaced by the macro definition.

You could do this instead:

```
#define LISTH "onus"

// and then
  printf(LISTH);
```

which the preprocessor will transform to:

```
  printf("onus");
```

If you do:

```
#define LISTH "onus";
```

the preprocessor will transform it to:

```
 printf("onus";);
```

which won't compile.

Comment: No, the preprocessor will transform it to `printf("onus";);`, which will not even compile.

Comment: @pmg and AndreyT  Thanks for pointint this out, I forgot the `;`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can't use `.` in macro names.

Secondly, you should "expect" it to print `ouns;`, since you included a `;` into your macro definition.

Thirdly, in order to achieve that you can use "stringization" macro-operator `#` with some helper macros

```
#define TO_STRING_(x) #x
#define TO_STRING(x) TO_STRING_(x)


#define LIST_H onus
...
printf(" " TO_STRING(LIST_H) " ");
```

or, better

```
printf(" %s ", TO_STRING(LIST_H));
```

Comment: Why do you need the second macro?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: I don't want to describe the whole thing in a comment (search for it yourself), but if you want to use macros as arguments to other macros, you generally needed to define your macros in this tow-leveled way, so that argument substitution works as you intended.

Comment: Basically, if you use a one-level macro `#define TO_STRING(x) #x` then `TO_STRING(LIST_H)` will expand to `"LIST_H"` instead of `"onus"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIST_H "onus"

int main()
{
    printf(LIST_H);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

macros in strings aren't resolved, you need to layers of macro resolution to do that:

```
#define __STR(x) #x
#define _STR(x) __STR(x)

printf(_STR(LIST));
```

you also cannot have dots in macro defines last I checked, which would be what your error is about, so rather use `LIST_H`...